# I'm drawing a blank on my name, help me out?

Tags: cipher

I'm **a wrestler**, I know that because I just got hit over the head harder than I've ever been hit before. So hard, in fact, that while I'm trying to remember my name... all that comes up in my head is:

```
...            ......  ...       ...              
...            ......             
...                 ......             ...   ...                        
...                  ......                     ......      ...
```

I'm certain **my name isn't blank**... and I'm pretty sure my name **isn't in Morse code**...

Going to see my doctor now for possible amnesia, but need my name to check in.

Help me out here?

**Hint:**

> I think smock was on the right track, but slightly off and missing another part of the puzzle. 
>  I may be drawing a blank but I'm drawing dots too. Maybe I'm remembering each letter one at a time with pauses (ellipses) between them!

Comment: Wrestlers don't really hit that hard, the show must go on ;)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier my memory's a little fuzzy but the blow to the head sure as heck wasn't <s>in the script</s> a move I was expecting!

Comment: My god he's got a steel chair!!!

Comment: @El-Guest In the famous words of [Ric Flair](https://twitter.com/RicFlairNatrBoy): "**Wooooooooooooooooo!**"

Comment: I'm thinking the spaces are significant here, as there are some at the end of the lines.

Comment: As The Rock would say: "It doesn't matter what your name is!"

Comment: any chance of a hint?

Comment: @el-guest I found [this](https://i.imgur.com/IHgmye2.gifv) on reddit today and thought of your comment LOL.

Comment: That brought a smile to my face! Thanks @MagicOctopusUrn!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your name is

> MACHO MAN RANDY SAVAGE.

Because:

> Notice that the dots come in 3 or 6. Counting the number of spaces between every 3 dots gives 
>  
>  12-0-2-7-14 
>  12-0-13 
>  17-0-13-3-24 
>  18-0-21-0-6-4 
>  
>  Converting 0 to A, 1 to B, and so on, 
>  
>  MACHO 
>  MAN 
>  RANDY 
>  SAVAGE

Comment: Hehe, I was hoping the A's aligning would make it slightly harder for brains to pick up on them, nice job.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping all the spaces out for a character just to see how that looks:

`...############......##...#######...##############
...############......#############
...#################......#############...###...########################
...##################......#####################......######...####`

Looking at that I get a sequence of numbers:

> 12-2-7-14
>   12-13
>   17-13-3-24
>   18-21-6-4

swapping for letters of the alphabet:
L-B-G-N
L-M
Q-M-C-X
R-U-F-D

Think I might be barking up the wrong tree here :-/
Am I anywhere near the right track?

Comment: Downvote likely because this is random ideation, not question answering.  My usual guidance here:  (... so how does this contribute toward a solution? As this stands, it's *Not an Answer*, not even a partial one. Having fragmentary thoughts on aspects of a puzzle might be comment-worthy, but you probably want at least a germ of an idea that seems to lead forward before you should post as even a partial answer.)

Comment: very difficult to put this kind of formatting in a comment though... Tempted to just not bother trying to figure this out and just delete this answer though. Depressing when an honest attempt to get somewhere with a puzzle is just stamped on.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter; I'll post hints later if nobody gets it.

Comment: @rubio he has a fair point though, the format I made it in wasn't quite suited to the site..

Comment: Sorry, was just being a bit moody! think we might need a hint or two :)

Comment: @Smock added a hint, yes you're on the right track but you missed something pretty key.